# Is it possible to make a label behave as a form field?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Can I make a label somehow behave as a form field? I added a name field and it does not work.

```
{
  xtype: 'label',
  name: 'id'
}
```

However this works :

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  name: 'id'
}
```

Should I just use a textfield and strip away its border?

UPDATE :

I am using a displayfield, and that seems to work. But, apart from changing the background colour, I cannot change any other properties of this using style.

```
{
    flex: 1,
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    text: 'rollout',
    style: 'font-size: 26px; background-color: #B6DAFF; ', //font size does not work :( Only background color does.
    padding: '0',
    margin: 0,
    name: 'status',
    width: 100
}
```

Comment: "Inspect Element" in a browser of your choice will show that font size won't work because `style` is set on the parent div, and subsequently overwritten for inner elements. You can try to set font-size using displayfield.getEl().setStyle, or by searching the input element in displayfield.innerHtml

Comment: I just thought that maybe you wanted to change the font-size of the label, not that of the displayfield. In that case, use displayfield.labelEl.setStyle

Comment: labelEl is a property in my displayfield config?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-property-labelEl states that `labelEl : Ext.Element` is a property, not a config option, and that it is "Only available after the component has been rendered."

Comment: hmmm thats a shame. Its weird that you can change styles in a label, but a displayfield, has to be changed via CSS. Seems pretty messy to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to populate label in form panel. Please try below code

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [{
        xtype:'label',          
        text: 'Send To:',
        style: 'font-size: 26px; background-color: #B6DAFF; ',
    }]
});
```

Comment: As per OP, it should "behave as a form field", which means that it should be populated automatically with a field value when a record is loaded into the form.

Comment: yes, exactly what Alexander said. I need a label that bahaves like a form field, where I can set the style inline